# Showing UISearchBar "X" within text field vs. adjacent Cancel button

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, cancel-button

I know I can set **showsCancelButton** to `NO` for a **UISearchBar** ... until you tap the search bar text field, and then the cancel button appears anyway! (At least it does for me.)

Is there a way to show the "X" in a circle within the **UISearchBar** text field vs. having that separate Cancel button show up adjacent to it? Note that this button only appears for me when search mode is active, and this is regardless of the setting for **showsCancelButton**.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // only show the status bar's cancel button while in edit mode
    mySearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

}
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    mySearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

when using this cancel button will not shown.

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. When I add that in, the Cancel button still shows up as soon as I enter edit mode, even as I trace through the line making the setting.

Comment: from where you added UIsearchbar?

Comment: Yup. The minute I go to edit the text in the search bar, the cancel button flies in to the right.

Wait a sec. Are you using UISearchBar on its own, or as part of the new-to-3.0 UISearchDisplayController? (I'm using the latter.)

Comment: i still haven't use the new UISearchDisplayController.it's available only in 3.0. i have used UISearchBar because my project was in 2.0 OS.You can try using UISearchBAr instead of UISearchDisplayController.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [searchBar subviews]) {

    if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {

         [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setClearsOnBeginEditing:YES];
    }
}
```

to enable the cancelButton try `searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;`
Try the above lines of code.

Comment: Thanks! I tend to be skittish about wandering through subviews in this fashion (unless it's documented), but you've certainly exercised due diligence here. To confirm, does the Cancel button remain or is it gone when this is executed?

Comment: after executing this code it will show the x symbol in textfield, if you want to enable cancelbutton  set showsCancelButton=YES check out my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

if you use interface builder it is ery easy to show.it is there by default.i have used search bar in my app and the searchbartextfield has an "X" to clear the textfield

Comment: To clarify my question: I'm asking if there's a way to show the "X" in a circle vs. (that is, _instead_ of) having that separate Cancel button show up next to it. Yes, the "X" in a circle will certainly appear once you start entering text, but the Cancel button will remain, regardless of the setting for showsCancelButton.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the "X" is only intended to clear the search field and not to cancel the search, and so the Cancel button must remain once a search is in play, regardless of **showsCancelButton**.